# Dynamic memory Allocation in Linked list insert function

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list, dynamic-memory-allocation

I was going through a tutorial on Linked Lists in C++. I found the following code for the implementation for inserting an element in the Linked List:

```cpp
/* Given a reference (pointer to pointer) to the head
of a list and an int, appends a new node at the end */
void append(Node** head_ref, int new_data)
{
    /* 1. allocate node */
    Node* new_node = new Node();
 
    Node *last = *head_ref; /* used in step 5*/
 
    /* 2. put in the data */
    new_node->data = new_data;
 
    /* 3. This new node is going to be
    the last node, so make next of
    it as NULL*/
    new_node->next = NULL;
 
    /* 4. If the Linked List is empty,
    then make the new node as head */
    if (*head_ref == NULL)
    {
        *head_ref = new_node;
        return;
    }
 
    /* 5. Else traverse till the last node */
    while (last->next != NULL)
        last = last->next;
 
    /* 6. Change the next of last node */
    last->next = new_node;
    return;
}
```

In step 1, we are declaring a pointer with name `new_node` and it is pointing to a dynamically created block.

What I couldn't understand is that, if the function is called 4 times then how can a new pointer variable with the same name be created on each call? Since we are using dynamic memory allocation, therefore it won't be dumped when we return from function.

So, how is this piece of code working?

Comment: Because this is working as designed and some other function is responsible for `delete`ing all the memory, in the linked list?

Comment: `new` doesn't create variables; it creates objects.  `new_node` is no different from any other local variable; it just happens to point to an object that has dynamic lifetime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable names don't exist at runtime, only at compile-time.

The `new_node` variable represents a chunk of memory that is local to the `append()` function.  Each time `append()` is called, a new memory chunk is created when it enters scope, and that chunk is released when it goes out of scope.

Each call to `new` allocates a new block of dynamic memory.  In this case, the memory address of that block is being stored inside that local memory chunk that `new_node` represents.

```
     append()                         
+----------------+                     
|   new_node     |                     
| +------------+ |      +-------------+
| | 0xABCDABCD |-|------| Node object |
| +------------+ |      +-------------+
+----------------+
```